# Is it possible that Hinduism was founded by a Prophet of Allah but has been changed into polytheism?

Tags: prophets, shirk, other-religions, hindu

According to Dr Zakir Naik, Allah is mentioned in Hindu scriptures:

> "Allah" in Rigveda Book 2 Hymn I verse II
>   Even in the Rigveda which is the most sacred scripture of the Hindus, one of the attributes given to God Almighty in Book no 2 Hymn no I verse II, is ‘Ila’ which if pronounced properly is the same as Allah.
>
> Allo Upanishad:
>   Amongst the various Upanishads one of the Upanishad is named as ‘Allo’ Upanishad in which God is referred to as "Allah" several times.

[***Source***](http://www.islam101.com/tauheed/Aior.htm)

> According to Bhavishya Purana in the Prati Sarag Parv III Khand 3 Adhay 3 Shloka 5 to 8.
>   "A malecha (belonging to a foreign country and speaking a foreign language) spiritual teacher will appear with his companions. His name will be Mohammad. Raja (Bhoj) after giving this Maha Dev Arab (of angelic disposition) a bath in the Panchgavya and the Ganga water (i.e. purifying him of all sins) offered him the present of his sincere devotion and showing him all reverence said, "I make obeisance to thee. O ye! The pride of mankind, the dweller in Arabia, Ye have collected a great force to kill the Devil and you yourself have been protected from the malecha opponents."

The Prophecy clearly states:

- The name of the Prophet as Mohammad.
- He will belong to Arabia. The Sanskrit word Marusthal means a sandy track of land or a desert.
- Special mention is made of the companions of the Prophet, i.e. the Sahabas. No other Prophet had as many companions as Prophet Muhammad (pbuh).
- He is referred as the pride of mankind (Parbatis nath). The Glorious Qur’an reconfirms this
- "And thou (standest) on an exalted standard of character"                          [Al-Qur'an 68:4]|
- "Ye have indeed in the Messenger of Allah, a beautiful pattern (of conduct)". [Al-Qur'an 33:21]
- He will kill the devil, i.e. abolish idol worship and all sorts of vices.
- The Prophet will be given protection against his enemy.
- Some people may argue that ‘Raja’ Bhoj mentioned in the prophecy lived in the 11th century C.E. 500 years after the advent of Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) and was the descendant in the 10th generation of Raja Shalivahan. These people fail to realise that there was not only one Raja of the name Bhoj. The Egyptian Monarchs were called as Pharaoh and the Roman Kings were known as Caesar, similarly the Indian Rajas were given the title of Bhoj. There were several Raja Bhoj who came before the one in 11th Century C.E.
- The Prophet did not physically take a bath in the Panchgavya and the water of Ganges. Since the water of Ganges is considered holy, taking bath in the Ganges is an idiom, which means washing away sins or immunity from all sorts of sins. Here the prophecy implies that Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) was sinless, i.e. Maasoom.

  [***Source***](http://www.islam101.com/religions/hinduism/Mhs.htm)

The above gives evidence of Allah and Muhammad.

**Question:** Is it possible that Hinduism was founded by a Prophet of Allah but has been changed into polytheism?

Comment: How is this primarily-opinion based?

Comment: Nobody knows the answer (except God), there will only be speculations here. And Zaik Naik use to be pretty biased in his questions. Maybe try asking in the Hinduism site for their point of view first of all?

Comment: I see this as the kind of question which requires experience to answer properly, so I have to disagree on the closure of this one.  [Users giving guesses in answers is not a fault of the question.]

Comment: Voting to close this as off-topic, it looks like it belongs  on [hinduism.se].

Comment: Maybe relevant : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/142/did-hindu-scriptures-predict-muhammad-and-or-jesus

Comment: @أرمان I will tell you 1 thing: Never believe the Bhavishya Purana. Its highly interpolated. Plus if you carefully study it, Muhammad is shown as the incarnation of an asura i.e. demon Tripurasura. Most scholars highly the doubt its authenticity so don't even use it to link Muhammad with Hinduism. And also don't believe whatever Zakir Naik says. No offense if you like him but he has virtually cherrypicked verses from Hindu scriptures to show Islam as a superior religion.

Comment: I agree with @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury the bhavishya puran is subject of controversy, because many of people may have changed the text, and this is because we're living in kaliyuga and kali demaon is king of this yuga, check my answer and don't forgot to read the last link. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that you ask the people over at [Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/) about whether the given *scripture* is authentic or properly interpreted by Zakir Naik. Unfortunately I've seen many of his claims, from statistics to arabic to interpretations of the bible, being taken out of context or plain wrong.

If you ask about the *possibility* of Hinudism being founded by a Prophet, then it is always possible. Allah tells us that mankind started on monotheism, and that He sent a prophet to every nation to guide them:

> [Quran 10:19](https://quran.com/10/19) And mankind was not but one community [united in
>   religion], but [then] they differed. And if not for a word that
>   preceded from your Lord, it would have been judged between them
>   [immediately] concerning that over which they differ.
>
> [Quran 16:36](https://quran.com/16/36) And We certainly sent into every nation a messenger,
>   [saying], "Worship Allah and avoid Taghut." And among them were those
>   whom Allah guided, and among them were those upon whom error was
>   [deservedly] decreed. So proceed through the earth and observe how was
>   the end of the deniers.
>
> [Quran 4:164](https://quran.com/4/164) And [We sent] messengers about whom We have related
>   [their stories] to you before and messengers about whom We have not
>   related to you. And Allah spoke to Moses with [direct] speech.

However ascribing a divine origin to Hinduism is pure speculation. Without a clear confirmation in the Quran or Hadith nothing can be said with certainty.
We know from experience that there are religions that  are not founded upon by a true Prophet (e.g Sikhs, Bahais, Mormons etc.)

It is better to avoid speaking about Allah without divine knowledge:

> [Quran 3:66](https://quran.com/3/66) Here you are - those who have argued about that of
>   which you have [some] knowledge, but why do you argue about that of
>   which you have no knowledge? And Allah knows, while you know not.
>
> [Quran 17:36](https://quran.com/17/36) And do not pursue that of which you have no
>   knowledge. Indeed, the hearing, the sight and the heart - about all
>   those [one] will be questioned.
>
> [Quran 7:33](https://quran.com/7/33) Say, "My Lord has only forbidden immoralities ... and
>   that you say about Allah that which you do not know."

Regarding whether the scriptures of Hinduism *could* be divine revelation, there is a group of scholars who have claimed that only three books have been revealed, based on the following:

> [Quran 6:156](https://quran.com/6/156) [We revealed it] lest you say, "The Scripture was
>   only sent down to two groups before us, but we were of their study
>   unaware,"

Though some have disputed this and interpreted the above verse to mean that the Meccans only knew of two.

So to sum up:  الله اعلم

Answer (score 2):

I am from India, and Dr Zakir Naik is not good person both in the eye of Hindu and Indian muslim person.  Checkout quora to know yourself.

1. [Ila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ila_(Hinduism)) does not mean allah, she is goddes.
2. And [allopanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allopanishad) is written by mughal empire, not buy GOD or ved vyas.

Let me tell you more about our religion(Sanatan Dharma).

Hinduism is the oldest religion, and we are following from satayuga, where people live happy and [dharma has four legs(austerity, cleanliness, mercy and truthfulness).](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3092/10405).

Then Treta, Dwapara and kaliyuga is stared. And in kaliyuga((Which started before 3102 BCE) the dharma is stand with only one leg and that is truthfullness, and that's why we still have access to vedas(Which are the oldest scripture in hinduism).

But kaliyuga is run by [kali deamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_(demon)), and due to this deamon (this deamon abode is gambling, liquor, prostitution, slaughter and gold, so this is everywhere in this planet), we have lost so many ancient books about the past yugas, and the bhavisyana puran is one of among them, people may have changed so many texts. But the prophet mohammad is not presented in good form, instead it is presented in bad form, something like this.

> Verses 10-27 relates next that Suta Goswami explained: After hearing
>   the king’s prayers and being pleased with him, Lord Shiva said: "Let
>   the King go to Mahakaleshwar (Ujjain) in the land of Vahika, which is
>   now contaminated by mlecchas. O King, the land where you are standing,
>   that is popular by the name of Bahik, has been polluted by the
>   mlecchas. In that terrible country there no longer exists Dharma.
>   There was a mystic demon named Tripura (Tripurasura), whom I have
>   already burnt to ashes once before, he has come again by the order of
>   Bali. He has no origin but he achieved a benediction from me. His name
>   is Mahamada and his deeds are like that of a ghost. Therefore, O king,
>   you should not go to this land of the evil ghost. By my mercy your
>   intelligence will be purified." [This would seem to indicate that this
>   Mahamada was an incarnation of the demon Tripura.] So hearing this,
>   the king came back to his country and Mahamada came with them, but
>   only to the bank of the river Sindhu. He was expert in expanding
>   illusion, so he said to the king very pleasingly, "O great king, your
>   god has become my servant. Just see, as he eats my remnants, so I will
>   show you."
>
> The king became surprised when he saw this happening before them. Then
>   in anger Kalidasa, the king’s commander, rebuked Mahamada, "O rascal,
>   you have created an illusion to bewilder the king, I will kill you,
>   you are the lowest..." Then the king left that area.
>
> Later, in the form of a ghostly presence, the expert illusionist
>   Mahamada appeared at night in front of King Bhojaraja and said: "O
>   King, your religion is of course known as the best religion among all.
>   Still, by the order of the Lord, I am going to establish a terrible
>   and demoniac religion and enforce a strong creed over the meat-eaters
>   [mlecchas]. My followers will be known by their cut [circumcised]
>   genitals, they will have no shikha [tuft of hair on their head, like
>   Brahmanas], but will have a beard, make noise loudly, and eat all
>   kinds of animals except swine without observing any rituals. They will
>   perform purificatory acts with the musala, and thus be called
>   musalman, and not purify their things with kusha grass [one of the
>   Vedic customs]. Thus, I will be the originator of this adharmic
>   [opposed to Vedic or Aryan Dharma] and demoniac religion of the
>   meat-eating nations." After having heard all this, the Bhavishya
>   Purana goes on to relate that King Bhojaraja returned to his land and
>   palace, and that ghost of the man also went back to his own place.

[@Source](https://www.stephen-knapp.com/mohammed_is_he_really_predicted_in_bhavishya_purana.htm)

[And this source might also help you.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8095/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A6-is-not-islamic-muhammad-its-a-sanskrit-word-and-it-has-its-own-meaning)

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate.

Answer (score 0):

Allo uponishad is not part of hindusm... It is totally frod by Demon akbar..Hindusm is world first religion...Even Islamic ADAM was hindu...Yes..He Is in Sree lanka which was 100% hindu...He is MANU... In vedas Manu was first man in earth..He first make man foot print... In.sree lanka..And he was brahmman.... In quran there are not mention that.. Adam was muslim.or nor...

Comment: Quran explicitly mentions that Adam was a submitter . Which Quran you are talking of ?